# How can I run Citrix Receiver on 13.04 x64?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, citrix, motif

I am trying to install Citrix receiver on Ringtail and I seem to be having a dependency issue. I have installed the correct architecture, but it requires a separate install of Open Motif. OpenMotif install fails: "Dependency is not satisfiable: xlibs-dev." Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after virgin install of 13.04.

Found this article [What to do after installing Ubuntu 13.04](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-13-04-aka-raring-ringtail-operating-system/)

Inside it found these 2 things that worked for be

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Then followed instructions on [CitrixICAClientHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) again Citrix worked, problem seemed to be nspluginviewer was still 32-bit and I had not installed the ia32-libs correctly until I did 2 things above.

Answer (score 1):

This walkthrough was able to get Citrix Receiver installed (and circumvent Citrix's install package errors) for me:

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/12/22/installing-citrix-receiver-on-ubuntu-64bit/

If you still run into issues, let us know how you're trying to install the package (ie: via Software Center?  dpkg?  etc.).  You may want to `remove icaclient` via `apt-get` first, before doing anything else.  It seems Citrix's install package is rather finicky and not working in a lot of cases.